# Display Product Variants on a page in Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I am looking to find out how i can display a products variants on a page in Shopify. Currently I have a page where I have hard coded a products quantity and size and then linked the price to the product page where the dropdowns for the variants are then predefined.

The problem is that if any variants are changed or any new ones are added then this will not reflected unless its hard coded, hence I need to have some sort of automation so the page correlates what it is available.

From what I know I would probably need to write a custom template, but not sure how i can go about doing this.

The following is an example of what I am looking to do.

Product - Cards

Quantity - 5 10 15 20 25
Style -    A A  A  A  A

Would appreciate it, if anybody is able to help or guide me as to how i can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more details. Add your code maybe?

Comment: Thanks HymnZ, I can share a link for my site but its password protected. At the moment I have used basic html code to display the price links and then copied the URL from selecting the different variants, but need an automatic solution...

Answer (score 0):

1). You can check with old backup files
 2). Created new test store and check product.liquid file

Shopify provide script to get variant in it's default file.